# Not able to establish a connection with redis cache running inside AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, redis, aws-fargate

We have a python project where we are trying to implement caching mechanism using `redis` cache running in AWS. From the code, we have the given the connection string for `redis` like below:

```
redis = Redis(host=cache_endpoint, username=cache_username, password=cache_password, ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs="none")
```

We are trying to check the value returned by return `redis.ping()`.

We also added the security group of the `redis` cache in config file which is `template.yml` and verified the endpoint, user name and password details are correct.

But we are not able to establish a connection with `redis`. The error which we are getting mentioned below:

```
ERROR:root:Error -2 connecting to redis://master.####.d####.region.cache.amazonaws.com:6379. Name or service not known.
```

We installed `redis` in our local machine and changed the connection string to local host and we were able to establish a connection. i.e., the `redis.ping()` returns true when we try to connect with `redis` running in the local machine, but not working with `redis` running in `AWS`.

Please give us some input to troubleshoot?

Actual,  the result, and expected result was mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: Please clarify, is the Python code running in AWS Fargate (ECS)? You added the `aws-fargate` tag but provided no information on how it is related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to AWS redis inside a VPC from your local machine directry.

Try to deploy your code to a machine (EC2, Lambda, ECS,...) inside the same VPC, configure your redis security group to allow connection from that machine. You can also ping redis from that machine to test first.

You can also use that machine as an SSH tunnel or Proxy to connect to that Redis, either way you need an instance anyway.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. We already created a redis cache in AWS and we pushed the code into  AWS ECS and we found the error in AWS Cloudwatch. The redis cache and repo are running in the same VPC. Also we have configured the security group of redis in the respective repo by adding in the config file (i.e., template.yml) file. Do I need to make any changes in docker file or any other file ?

Comment: No you don't need to. What's the error in cloudwatch?